# Is there an online code editor for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an online code editor for Ruby on Rails ?

To directly edit files on the server ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a problem and you thought editing files on the server could be the solution to that - if you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve you are more likely to find a good (if unexpected) answer.

Comment: I don't see this as necessarily being a bad question but the solution wouldn't be as simple as the asker expects or perhaps even what they are asking. A cloud based development/staging/testing environment from which you can deploy to production would be really useful. Not needing to always have a dev environment installed machine close to hand for one thing. Smart phone production bug fixes another.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is an online editor that supports Ruby syntax highlighting and FTP or SFTP access to directly edit the files on the server, look into [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com). It also supports access to Github and Bitbucket.

However, it does not support any Rails commands (like `generate` or `rake`). Also, you'd have to restart the server (like `touch tmp/restart.txt`) in order to show any changes you made to any files that require the server to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely hope the answer to this question is still "No".

What exactly are you wanting to edit on the server? If the answer is view templates, then look into [Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) - you can provide an admin for template bits that you store in the database.

Editing (let alone displaying) application code via a web interface is madness. Allowing users to enter evaluated code is crazy. I have an app that lets users enter formulas, but these are expressed in a mathematical grammar parsed by [polyglot](http://polyglot.rubyforge.org/)/[treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) - not in Ruby code. Application code should be written - with tests - on a dev. machine and only deployable by trusted users.

Nevermind that if you were updating the code on a server, you'd need to tell the app server to reload the code.